# force div element to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

[image: application for project]
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqQJNM code pen for html and the css 
I am trying to force the picture of the items to the top or the middle of the picture of the character I am not really sure how this is done any help? I have tried vertical-align different positions css is my weakest region so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#information{
background-color: CCFFFF;
border: groove;
width:100%;
height: 230px;
}

#summonerBox{
width: : 100px;
background-color: ;

}
#summonerInput{
width:200px;
height: 20px;
background-color: white;
}
.winBg{
background-color: green;
}
.loseBg{
background-color: red;
}
#itemList1{
position: inherit;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 300px;
list-style-type: none;
vertical-align:top;


}
#itemlist2{
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 300px;
list-style-type: none;

}
#goldEarned{
list-style-type: none;


}
#gameType{
list-style-type: none;


}
#summonerGame{
list-style-type: none;

}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you could create a code snippet or create a codepen with your HTML/CSS.

Comment: Could you post your HTML too ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqQJNM

Comment: I don't know how much it will help I can't post all my javascript to show what it is doing but that is the 2nd page of html

Answer (score 1):

```
Use positioning for the element which you want to fix to top
//For left align
#itemList1{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
//to fix it with respect to you device screen then just use {position:fixed;} instead.
//For center align first wrap all UL with any Divlike
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>...</ul>
  <ul>...</ul>
  ..
</div>
//CSS..
.wrapper{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:50%;
 right:50%;
 width:300px;
 margin-left:-150px
}

This will make all <ul> at the center of the screen and it will be responsive.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a simple solution :

```
#information{
    background-color: #CCFFFF;
    border: groove;
    width:100%;
    height: 230px;
    position: relative;
}

#summonerBox{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: ;
}

#summonerInput{
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}

.winBg{
    background-color: green;
}

.loseBg{
    background-color: red;
}

#itemList1{
    margin-left: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#itemlist2{
    margin-left: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
}

#goldEarned{
    list-style-type: none;
}

#gameType{
    list-style-type: none;
}

#summonerGame{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```